# Add QTY input field to related products block

Tags: magento

Good day.

I want to add qty input field to related products block in frontend in magento. 
(for example product view page.)

Maybe someone knows how can I do this ?

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in this file path

'app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Related.php'.

```
$this->addColumn('qty', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Qty'),
        'index'     => 'qty'
    ));
```

inside

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{

}
```

this function.

I hope it help to you.

Comment: maybe U know how I can add this field in frontend (product view page-> related products)??